# Secret Voting Without Commit/Reveal

Tags: zero-knowledge, voting

I am building a voting contract where people (who hold a certain ERC20 token) can vote to determine a binary outcome. The votes should be weighted with the amount of ERC20 tokens that the voters commited upon casting the vote. I would like the voting to have the following properties:

- It should be secret. No one should be able to tell what outcome has been voted for by each vote. Furthermore, it should not be visible how many tokens a voter commited to his vote (i.e. the weight of the vote must be hidden as well). Ideally, one can not even see how many and which addresses have voted. Everything can (but does not need to be) revealed after voting has ended.
- The voter should not be able to reveal his or her vote before the voting has ended. That means, the voter should not be able to go on a web forum and prove (e.g. via showing that he can create a specific hash or via signing something) that he or she voted for a certain outcome.
- Only one voting interaction should be necessary. (No commit/reveal pattern requiring two interactions)

Is something like this possible? Maybe with zero-knowledge proofs or homomorphic encryption? Maybe there are already some reference implementations?

Thank you very much!